# How could I add current pc IP into security group with aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to add current working PC's IP into a security group,

And enable all traffice for it. Every time I should do that manually with the web dashboard.

How could I do it with a shell script?

The following are the most common aws cli commands I used.

But I couldn't find how to add `ip` in a specific security group.

```
list_instances(){
    aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value,InstanceId,PublicIpAddress,PrivateIpAddress]' --output text
}
start_instance(){
    aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids $1
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a script that determines the current computer's IP address, then uses the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to add access for ports 22 (SSH) and 3389 (RDP) -- much safer than adding access on ALL ports.

```
# Retrieve current IP address
IP=`curl -s http://whatismyip.akamai.com/`

# Authorize access on ports 22 and 3389
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name "SG-NAME" --protocol tcp --port 22   --cidr $IP/32 --profile class --output text
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name "SG-NAME" --protocol tcp --port 3389 --cidr $IP/32 --profile class --output text
```

It assumes that the AWS CLI has access to credentials, either via Instance Metadata (on Amazon EC2 instances) or from a local credentials file configured via `aws configure`.

Comment: Hi thanks~~ but do you know how to do this in reverse way, i mean how could I remove existing IP from the security rule, thanks

Comment: Use `aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress`

Comment: How to allow all traffic from my PC ?

Comment: note: the group-name does not have to be unique so better use --group-id instead

Comment: this fails if the security group is not in the default VPC

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell version based on [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein)'s answer:

```
# Set Security Group name
$SG_ID="sg-903004f8"

# Retrieve current IP address
$IP=Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing http://whatismyip.akamai.com/

# Authorize access on ports 22 (SSH) and 3389 (RDP)
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id "$SG_ID" --protocol tcp --port 22   --cidr "$IP/32"
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id "$SG_ID" --protocol tcp --port 3389 --cidr "$IP/32"
```

Answer (score 1):

This PowerShell script cleans up the currently authorised IP before authorising the current one.

```
# Retrieve current IP address
$IP=Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing http://whatismyip.akamai.com/
$sg="sg-00001"
$old_file_path = 'old_ip.txt'

if(Test-Path -Path $old_file_path){
    $OldIp=Get-Content -Path $old_file_path
    aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id "$sg" --protocol tcp --port 8443 --cidr "$OldIp/32"
}

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id "$sg" --protocol tcp --port 8443 --cidr "$IP/32"

Set-Content -Path $old_file_path -Value $IP
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a tool that you can use and easily manage to whitelist your IP with a port in the AWS security group.
You can create and update the AWS security group rule using [aws_ipadd](https://github.com/piyushsonigra/aws_ipadd) command.

https://github.com/piyushsonigra/aws_ipadd

```
$ aws_ipadd my_project_ssh
  Your IP 12.10.1.14/32 and Port 22 is whitelisted successfully.

$ aws_ipadd my_project_ssh
  Modifying existing rule...
  Removing old whitelisted IP '12.10.1.14/32'.
  Whitelisting new IP '131.4.10.16/32'.
  Rule successfully updated!
```

Answer (score 1):

I´ve modified this from this source:- https://gist.github.com/niraj-shah/567da4146fe2912bb6b4626bc71471ea

Enjoy yourselves!

```
#!/bin/bash
# Retrieve current IP address

ip=$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org);
old_ip=$(head -1 $HOME/ActualIp.txt)

profile="default"
ports=(22 3306);
group_ids=(sg-087891bcfb9caea8d sg-013e1366ba61b6548);
fixed_ips=();


if [ "$ip" == "$old_ip" ]; then

        echo "nothing to do"

else
        for port in ${ports[@]}
        do
                for group_id in ${group_ids[@]}
                do

                        # Display security group name
                        echo -e "\033[34m\nModifying Group: ${group_id}\033[0m and port number: ${port}";

                        # Get existing IP rules for group
                        ips=$(aws ec2 --profile=$profile describe-security-groups --filters Name=ip-permission.to-port,Values=$port Name=ip-permission.from-port,Values=$port Name=ip-permission.protocol,Values=tcp --group-ids $group_id --output text --query 'SecurityGroups[*].{IP:IpPermissions[?ToPort==`'$port'`].IpRanges}')
                        ips=$(sed 's/IP//g' <<< $ips)

                        for ip in $ips
                        do
                                echo -e "\033[31mRemoving IP: $ip\033[0m"
                                # Delete IP rules matching port
                                aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --profile=$profile --group-id $group_id --protocol tcp --port $port --cidr $ip 
                        done
        # Get current public IP address
        myip=$(curl -s https://api.ipify.org);
        echo -e "\033[32mSetting Current IP: ${myip}\033[0m"

        # Add current IP as new rule
        aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --profile=$profile --protocol tcp --port $port --cidr ${myip}/32 --group-id $group_id
        #Print curret IP to a file for the next cron
        curl -s https://api.ipify.org > $HOME/ActualIp.txt

        # Loop through fixed IPs
        #for ip in $fixed_ips
        #do
        #echo -e "\033[32mSetting Fixed IP: ${ip}\033[0m"

        # Add fixed IP rules
        #/home/pi/.local/bin/aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --profile=$profile --protocol tcp --port $port --cidr ${ip} --group-id $group_id
        #done

                done
        done
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small shell script for the same, to check tomcat logs on ElasticBeanstalk:

```
#!/bin/sh
#myIp = my current dynamic IP
myIp=`curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'`
mySG=SSHSecurityGroup

#add my IP to security group
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-02aXXXXX --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $myIp/32 --profile=prod
echo `date` added shh access to stroll-env security group

#aws ec2 revoke-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-02aXXXXX --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $myIp/32 --profile=prod
echo `date` done...
```

**PS**: --protocol tcp --port 22 --profile=prod indicates that I'm adding ssh access to my prod (production) instances.

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this post while looking for the awscli command to update security group. I thought I would share this Python script I wrote using Boto3 and Requests recently that will update the stated security group with your current IP address. Hope this can help someone.

[https://github.com/JustinDevelops/AWS-SG-IP-Updater](https://github.com/JustinDevelops/AWS-SG-IP-Updater/)

Answer (score 0):

*This small bash script serves the same purpose, the port number can be a positional argument in cli -*

```
#!/bin/bash

TargetAddr='<IP>'
aws_sg_id='<sg-id>'

myip=$(curl -s ifconfig.me)

echo -e "Updating IP $myip in Security Group: $aws_sg_id"

aws --profile <profile-name> ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id $aws_sg_id  --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $myip/32 2>/dev/null

#Verifying the Access
/usr/bin/nc -zv -w1 $TargetAddr 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my bash script to allow your terminal's public IP address to port 5432(Postgres SQL)at the inbound rule.

Assume your security group is not in default VPC, so you can't use `--group-name`, but you only know your security group name.

```
--group-id (string)

The ID of the security group. You must specify either the security group ID or the security group name in the request. For security groups in a nondefault VPC, you must specify the security group ID.

--group-name (string)

[EC2-Classic, default VPC] The name of the security group. You must specify either the security group ID or the security group name in the request. For security groups in a nondefault VPC, you must specify the security group ID.
```

Then you can do like this

```
#!/bin/bash

sg_id=$(aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters Name=group-name,Values=your_security_group_name --query "SecurityGroups[*].[GroupId]" --output text)

public_ip=$(curl -s ifconfig.me)
echo "your public ip address is: $public_ip"

aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $sg_id \
    --protocol tcp \
    --port 5432 \
    --cidr $public_ip/24

echo "your public ip address have been added to the RDS sg inbound rule!"
```